# ImageData byte length is not a multiple of 4 * width

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am having an issue with creating `ImageData`. I am getting the following error message:

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to construct 'ImageData': The input data byte length is not a multiple of (4 * width).

Here is the method that I am running:

```
public setPixelData(data: Buffer, width: number, height: number) {
    var imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(data), width, height);
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

I have dumped the data and this is what is showing:

```
data = Uint8Array[632028]
width = 720
height = 720
```

So, what would be the cause of this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=632028%2F720

Comment: @blorgebeard: 1 upvote :)

Comment: when I did it on my calculator I was getting this: `158007`

Comment: I don't know how you came up with that, but `158007*4=632028`. Anyway, The error is saying that `632028/(720*4)` needs to be a round number.

Comment: I was dividing by 4 not 720. I am using electrons `nativeImage.toPNG()` It must not be returning the alpha values.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, apparently the array size needs to be the **multiple of width, height and 4**.
As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556730/imagedata-byte-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-4-width/41434004#comment77546016_41434004) pointed out correctly the multiplication with 4 is due to the RGBA color space, which consists of the four channels red, green, blue, and alpha.

So for your case: 720 * 720 * 4 equals 2073600

```js
var width = 720, height = 720;
var data = new ImageData(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(4 * width * height),
  720,
  720
);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your code seems to imply that you want an empty ImageData. If so, then use ctx.createImageData(width, height), which has support for all browsers supporting the canvas API (even IE9 which did not support TypedArray constructors).

Comment: My goal was to point out the cause of the error. If the questioner wants to create an ImageData object out of existing data, it is necessary to check if the given width and height matches the formula, or otherwise calculate them itself by the `Uint8ClampedArray.length`. Should I clearfy this in my answer?

Comment: to expand on this, it wants an array of red, green, blue, and alpha (opacity) for each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Height and Width of canvas must be eqaul in both Input canvas and output ImgData in which you are converting into.

```js
const frame = new ImageData(clampedArray, width, height);
```