# getScreenShot function returns error in v6

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am getting following error when `Viewer.getScreenShot(w, h, cb)` function is executed in viewer v6. It works correctly in v5.

Anyone knows how to get around this issue?

Thanks

> `viewer3D.min.js?v=6.0.*:63` Uncaught `DOMException`: Failed to construct `ImageData`: The input data length is not a multiple of `(4 * width)`.
>   at `e (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=6.0.*:63:24318)`
>   at `e.getScreenShot (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=6.0.*:63:24936)`
>   at `a.h.getScreenShot (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=6.0.*:57:21319)`

Comment: The release note https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v60 take a look

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but it doesn't indicate any change to getScreenShot() function. Thanks.

Comment: The function looks good, I have just verified the function in the console, it works good to get the screen shot: NOP_VIEWER.getScreenShot(1000,1000, function(url){window.open(url)}). Can you paster your code?

Comment: @ZhongWu My code is same as yours except sizes are 400 x 160. This is Chrome on macOS. What is your environment? So, I can verify it here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the issue. In v5, width and height were accepted as either int or float, but in v6, only int is accepted. Calculated dimensions should go through round() function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error pointed out, the input data length of ImageData should be a multiple of (4*width), since you input float value of w and h, the array size might be incorrect, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556730/imagedata-byte-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-4-width  for details.

Comment: Yes. I understood the issue. I couldn't realize it immediately because float values worked in v5. This error suddenly turned up when I switched to v6. Thanks.