# How to read image from disk with nodeJS to display in Canvas element

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, html5-canvas

I'm writing an electron app where a user will select an image from disk. I need to read the contents and display them in a canvas for editing purposes, and to do this I need to do two things:

1.) Read the contents of the image and put them in a Canvas

2.) Determine the dimensions of the image.

To achieve the first, I'm reading the file contents with fs.readFileSync:

```js
let imageData = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile);
```

This gets me a Uint8Array when loading up a PNG. To place it into my canvas I'm attempting to create an ImageData which requires a Uint8*Clamped*Array, so I'm attempting a conversion like this:

```js
let array = new Uint8ClampedArray(this.imageBuffer);
let imageData = new ImageData(array, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Error
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

However, while the file seems to load fine, there's obviously more work I need to do to get it onto a canvas because this gives an error stating:

"Failed to construct 'ImageData': The input data length is not a multiple of 4."

I'm assuming the data I'm reading straight from my PNG isn't in the correct format to write into an ImageData, so what can I do to format it correctly? And how would I be able to determine the dimensions of the original image with this data?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work but try `Uint8ClampedArray.from` instead of `new Uint8ClampedArray`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImageData byte length is not a multiple of 4 \* width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556730/imagedata-byte-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-4-width)

Comment: @grimsteel Nope, same behavior.

Comment: @about14sheep It might help me with part 1 of my problem, but highlights the importance of part 2 - that answer specifies that the array actually must be a multiple of 4 and the original image width*height, but I don't know how one would get those dimensions from the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Uint8Array` holds the binary data of your image file in whatever format it is, it's not the raw image data that `ImageData` requires.

Luckily for you [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) can accept binary data directly and decode it correctly to an `ImageBitmap`, exposing the image's dimension and that can be drawn to a canvas directly.

For this you'd need to pass a `Blob` though.
It seems that Electron's `fs` still doesn't provide a method to get a Blob from a path so we'll have to make one from the `Uint8Array`, which means we'll have to have the data twice in memory... (for a short time).

```js
const data = fs.readFileSync(pathToFile);
const bmp = await createImageBitmap(new Blob([data]));
const {width, height} = bmp;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! I had been going down a hole using libraries dedicated to parsing PNG data but this is native and doesn't limit me to ONLY PNGs. Thanks!